# Optical mouse not working after login screen

Tags: kernel, 16.04, mouse

I'm Using UBUNTU 16.04 and I connected a USB optical mouse to my laptop and It works in login page, But after login it stops working. The last output of `dmesg` is:

```
usb 2-1.3: input irq status -75 received
```

I restart my PC and Boot with older Kernels. But it not helped again. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to Gnome Software. To stop this from happening we can disable the Gnome Software from startup applications.

Here are the steps to solve this issue:-

1:-open the dash and search for "startup applications" and open it.

2:-Disable Gnome Software (Uncheck the box on the left side).

3:-close it

4:-shutdown or restart and check it again.

this time your mouse will start working.

but you should know that every time you start the Gnome Software(Ubuntu Software Center), your mouse will stop working again. To solve this type this command:-

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Toshiba laptop.

- First, login.
- Next, unplug the USB adapter.
- Finally, plug the USB adapter back in.

I have a keyboard and a mouse that both use the same Microsoft adapter. For some reason, the keyboard works fine after login but the mouse does not until I unplug the USB adapter and plug it back in.